# If this MySQL UPDATE statement becomes slow when the table grows huge, how to speed things up?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following simple MySQL UPDATE statement;

```
    UPDATE TableA
    SET columnX =
        (
            CASE
                WHEN (ColumnB = 'Criteria_Met')
                    then ( 0 )
            END 
        );
```

I am concerned that that the above UPDATE statement using CASE will be slow. This is because rows that do not meet the criteria will be assigned NULL. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

This means that if the table has millions of rows, all the rows that do not meet the criteria will be assigned null. This will take time if there are many rows. Wouldn't such an UPDATE statement be very slow? If yes, are there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column is already null, you don't need to update it again. So you could do something like the following:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET columnX = 
    (
        CASE
            WHEN (ColumnB = 'Criteria_Met')
                then ( 0 )
            ELSE null
        END 
    )
 WHERE columnX IS NOT NULL;
```

In this case you'll only be updating rows that are changing. It is also a good idea to index columnX and columnB so they can be scanned quickly.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
UPDATE TableA
  SET columnX = 0 
  WHERE ColumnB = 'Criteria_Met';
```

which meets the first code (ie, any record where previously columnX was 0 will stay at 0)

I would avoid any "case" in such a situation where a WHERE clause will be lots more efficient, and specially if ColumnB is indexed.

If we consider, as suggested by the second code, that columnX must be updated for all records, I would probably test the run times of running TWO queries:

```
UPDATE TableA SET ColumnX = NULL;
UPDATE TableA
  SET columnX = 0 
  WHERE ColumnB = 'Criteria_Met';
```